# ActiveRecord attribute_present? lies. How can I fix it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

The [docs for attribute_present?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods.html#method-i-attribute_present-3F) say:

> Returns true if the specified attribute has been set by the user or by
>   a database load ...

BUT... that's not true! We see [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/72d4d47216de66c8db391dcb88650fe4d76900d3/activerecord/lib/active_record/core.rb#L296) that Rails initializes attributes on a new object from database defaults.

So, suppose we have a users table with `age not null default 0`. Then

`User.new.attribute_present?(:age) == true`

But it hasn't been set by us OR a database load.

Perhaps I'm arguing semantics, but in any case, I'd like a method that does what it says: tells me if a field has been **explicitly set**.

e.g.

```
u = User.new
# u.attribute_set?(:age) == false
u.age = u.age #set explicitly to default, for example
# u.attribute_set?(:age) == true
```

Does that exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't a way (provided you have default arguments in your db) (as is good design)

Edited: edited from original answer based on Z5h's comments below

Comment: This will only tell me if it has changed from the default (or whatever it last was). I want to know if it has been explicitly set. The difference is subtle but important for my needs.

Comment: Then there is no way, provided you have default arguments in the db (as is good design)

Comment: if you update your answer to say some variant of: "there is no way, provided you have default arguments in the db (as is good design)" then I can accept it.

Comment: @z5h,  I like to take a break from work once in a while and help others, getting answers accepted is not a priority

Comment: I believe the statement "there is no way" is the correct answer and is a helpful addition to what you have already written. I'd like to help others by indicating that. It has nothing to do with points or accepted answers. Of course do not edit your content if you disagree.